# Redux Form - How to re-render when URL changes from same component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to re-render a ReduxForm integrated component when the url changes, but the component remains the same.

I have tried

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 if (this.props.history.location.pathname 
  !== nextProps.history.location.pathname){
  console.log('here, new route but same component!');
}
```

as well as the same for `componentDidUpdate`, but `nextProps` and `this.props` are the same!

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.location)
    console.log(prevProps.location);
    // These two are the same!
  }
```

Also, I can't access `nextProps.params` -  ReduxForm or `connect` is changing the `this` object for the component, leaving me utterly confused on how to even register if the URL has changed.

I would prefer not to use `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the original this.props.history.location.pathname to a variable in state to "cache" it. I think at the time componentWillRecieveProps is being called

this.props is the same as nextProps

//something like this....

```
componentDidMount(){
this.setState({cachedURL: this.props.history.location.pathname})
}

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
if (this.state.cachedURL 
  !== nextProps.history.location.pathname){
  console.log('here, new route but same component!');
}
```

Comment: the problem is that nextProps is still not changing when the the URL is changing, so it's still checking against itself